# Outdoor Interface Lighting

Tags: interface, light

Sorry to anticipate if it is not the right place.

I have 2 questions regarding the same topic:

- What type of screen would you use for outdoor use? Matte backlit LCD?
- What background and text colors can I use for better readability? Do you know any study?

Greetings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best color combination for on screen reading?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/what-is-the-best-color-combination-for-on-screen-reading)

Comment: Please separate the questions and aim for specific answers, as the questions are too broad in their current form.