# How to provide non-visual feedback on a touch screen?

Tags: touch-screen, haptics

How do you provide feedback for blind people or low-vision people for clicks on a touch screen? What technology is used? I heard iPhone provides this kind of feedback; what it is?

Comment: Related: [Why touchscreens?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/86775/13161) and [International standards for light switches?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/87883/13161). If you do not have an ad-hoc touchscreen then you have only two available feedbacks: audio and vibration (but in this case **locate** controls is more problematic).

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here. Are you asking how blind people *currently* interact with touch screens? Or are you looking to introduce a new feature yourself? Apple devices already have [VoiceOver](http://www.apple.com/uk/accessibility/ios/voiceover/) built in.

Comment: There are many ways of communicating shapes and textures on a touch screen device. A good starting point for learning about this technology is [Disney Research](http://www.disneyresearch.com/project/3d-touch-surfaces/).

Answer (score 1):

You can go for haptic feedback. Provided the user has enabled haptic feedback in settings.

Comment: Please extend your answer with more of your reasoning so that people can weigh up the merits of your suggestion.  Simply giving a solution is less helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, other people already said it although in a very simple way, so here it goes again (credits to them): what you're looking for is called **Haptic Feedback**, which is one of the components of a [**Haptic Interface**](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3638/haptic-interface)

> A haptics interface is a system that allows a human to interact with a
>   computer through bodily sensations and movements. Haptics refers to a
>   type of human-computer interaction technology that encompasses tactile
>   feedback or other bodily sensations to perform actions or processes on
>   a computing device.

Haptic Technology is so common and popular it replaced the original name this technology had, which is [**kinesthetic communication**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_technology). However, now is more common to hear the word **Haptics** (one word, plural) for this technology

While **Haptics** is NOT only for visually impaired, but has a lot of uses in **VR, gaming, medical and high tech devices**, this technology is often used in devices for the visually impaired as well as devices for people with some neurological disorders.

More important: **Haptics** is so common that as an example, it's what is used for a simple "incoming message" vibration, or some gaming console peripherals, so its use is really wide and growing every day.